# For Loop in R. How can I save the outputs?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am trying to save each value from this for loop into a vector:

```
for (i in 1:10000){
  mean((rbinom(1000,5,0.7)))
}
```

But I have not been successful in doing so.

I know I need to create the vector before the loop and call it inside it, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Are you aware that you never use the loop variable `i` inside the loop?

Comment: Yea, I did it because I needed it to run a fixed amount of 10000 times. Originally i just printed the results, so I knew the code worked. I'm just lost how to place it into a vector.

Comment: Just use `rep(mean(...), 10000)`, there is no need for an explicit loop.  Still I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It was just a homework problem that suggested using a for loop to solve, but the teacher never went over them. Only my 3rd assignment on r so I don't know too much yet.

Comment: There is a problem with `rep(..)`: it will repeat always the same value. I suggest using `replicate()` instead, as posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a `for` loop, you could do something like:

```
means.vec <- replicate(10000, mean(rbinom(1000,5,0.7)))
```

If you *really* need a for loop, you can try:

```
means.vec <- vector()
for (i in 1:10000) {
   means.vec[i] <- mean(rbinom(1000,5,0.7))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed a for loop would be the easiest but this is much better.